# Bike is not starting after 1-2 days of sitting idle

Tags: starting, scooter, activa

My bike is an Activa 3G.  It is a one month old bike. I use the bike only once in 2-3 days or sometimes alternate days. So it will be in an unmoved condition for 2-3 days wholly and sometimes 1 day completely. When I try to start it, it will not start. Even after multiple tries. It never starts up. I apply the choke and try it. With the choke, after 5-7 tries, it is getting started.

Now, I would like to know whether the problem is with any part of the engine?

Why am I unable to start the engine even with multiple attempts without applying the choke?

Appreciate if you could share me your valuable views...Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Typical Honda scooter problem. My month old Activa 5G takes at least 25 kicks to start if it stays idle for more than 48 hrs. It has been checked by the service guys for 5 times already and no solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to apply the choke when starting a cold engine.  Until the engine is at operating temperature, it needs to run a bit rich to run properly.  The choke allow the engine to run rich.

5-7 tries does sound a bit much.  Is there a way of priming the engine to ensure fuel is getting into there before cranking?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of not getting started means that there may be a problem with self-start mechanism or battery (in most cases since it is not an old vehicle). Unless you are not having a very cold day, always apply Choke. If not, then observe the sound from Engine that Self Starter usually makes while you Crank start the engine. If it is feeble or unusual, then it may be that battery is not getting charged enough or it is getting discharged fast.

Remember to blame on Self Starer or on battery only if you are easily able to kick start and cannot do it with battery.